# Google App Engine Patch - How to use stylesheets?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Struggling with an install of GAE-Patch and using my stylesheets. My settings.py has the following lines included already, but the media generator is not compiling and packaging it properly:

```
    'combined-%(LANGUAGE_DIR)s.css': (
        'global/look.css',
    ),
    'combined-%(LANGUAGE_DIR)s.css': (
        'global/base-%(LANGUAGE_DIR)s.css',
        'owr/main.css',
    ),
```

and

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'owr',
)
```

Where is the stylesheet supposed to go, in which folder? Under owr/media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the app.yaml file:

It should look like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /media
    static_dir: _generated_media
```

This means that you need to put your css, etc in the _generated_media folder.

Comment: Hmm, I have the css in the generated media folder, but it's still not working. What is the correct path one should be linking to in the actual html? I have tried href="owr/main.css", owr/media/main.css, media/main.css etc. Am I required to run the generate media command after making changes?